Spark Task Hangs after MySQL Query Aborted
Running PySpark 3.3.2, using mysql-connector-java version 8.0.27, MySQL version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.3 hosted on RDS.
I have a set of scheduled spark jobs that query MySQL. Typically, these MySQL queries take 20-40 minutes depending on the size of the table. I have observed intermittent runtime spikes, where a single spark task appears to be stuck and eventually succeeds after hanging for ~2-2.5 hours.
In each instance this has occurred, I have found that a single executor has had a single unfinished task. The hung task's query was aborted in MySQL, with an error of the form:
<timestamp> [Note] Aborted connection <connection> to db: '<db name>' user: '<user>' host: '<hung executor IP>' (Got timeout writing communication packets

The aborted queries ran for a 'typical' amount of time, i.e. a particular table's queries generally take 36-38 minutes. In the instance where the task hung, the query began around 16:00 UTC, executed for 37 minutes, and was aborted at 16:36 UTC. My Spark executor has log statments around 16:37UTC as the other 3/4 tasks completed. After the query was aborted, the issuing Spark task was in the RUNNING state for an additional ~2 hours and the executor logged no statements until 18:18 UTC, logging JDBCRDD: closed connection prior to throwing the following error:
java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:82)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.StatementIsClosedException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:341)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:948)
    ... 15 more


I am passing in a query timeout of 45 minutes as the 'queryTimeout' parameter to my DataFrameReader.
I am expecting my Spark task to fail and retry after its query is aborted, not hang for 2 hours and eventually fail with "java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed." Has anyone encountered a similar issue/have a resolution?
